# Managing digital assets... backwards

Tags: software-recommendation, asset-management

Is there a program/resource that allows you to track graphics files—for instance an Illustrator or Photoshop file—and will list all InDesign or Illustrator files where that asset is used? Bridge doesn't seem to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, no file has any no clue where it may or may not be used moving forwards.

Customarily assets can only be collected from the collective file, not the the individual pieces that make up the collection. I've never heard of any asset collection that can somehow magically know where the asset was used just by looking at the asset.

The link between files is created in the main file via a references to the included asset(s). There's no software I know that then embeds some sort of subscribe link in the original asset file(s) so they know where they are used.

Comment: It is technically a bit challenging yes, but that does not mean you couldn't track a file within your own system with a little bit of pedantry form a users side. So it is in fact possible to scan your own repository for links caused by placing therefore if you have the reverse links a graph could be constructed by the asset manager. Its a bit painful to implement, and fragile so that's why i doubt any vendor would want to sell such a system but still possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that NeoFinder can 'look inside' documents in a search such as a PDF.  Maybe it'll see the list of links inside, for example, an InDesign file. I asked the question at the NeoFinder site and will update you when I hear back!